# How to add keyboard shortcuts permanently to Jupyter (ipython) notebook?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, startup, jupyter

I have the following configuration for shortcuts, that works after running it in the cell of Jupiter notebook:

```
%%javascript


IPython.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts.add_shortcut('ctrl-q', {
    help: 'Clear all output',               // This text will show up on the help page (CTRL-M h or ESC h)
    handler: function (event) {             // Function that gets invoked
        if (IPython.notebook.mode == 'command') {
            IPython.notebook.clear_all_output();
            return false;
        }
        return true;                   
    }
  });
```

How can I setup Jupiter notebook to make this initialization automatically on startup?

I tried adding the same code (without `%%javascript`) to `C:\Users\<username>\.ipython\profile_default\static\custom\custom.js` but it didn't work.

I have only one profile, created with `ipython profile create`, Python 3.3, Windows 7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: note that for jupyter `custom.js` is located at `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

custom.js is the correct place for this code. Try wrapping it as follows (don't forget the `return true` before the end of the block):

```
$([IPython.events]).on("app_initialized.NotebookApp", function () {
    <your code>

    return true;
});
```

Comment: Do you really believe that "<your code>" is enough information for someone to create a keyboard shortcut using your method?!

Answer (score 10):

In the new version of [Jupyter notebook](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Custom%20Keyboard%20Shortcuts.html) (update it either with `pip install --upgrade notebook` or if you use conda `conda upgrade notebook`), you can customize them from the notebook itself.

To do this <kbd>Help</kbd> -> <kbd>Edit keyboard shortcuts</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Note this doesn't solve keyboard shortcuts for editing mode, only command mode. Thus while `enter command mode` is ostensibly available, it is not actually set by this interface.

Comment: This is also not persistent

Comment: @Celtor it was persistent for me on Jupyter 4.4.0, was saved under `~/.jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I am trying to assign a shortcut to `restart kernel and run all cells` but once I save from the dialog and then reopen the dialog the shortcut is gone. It doesn't work at all

Comment: I have used "Edit Keyboard Shortcuts" and did some customization quite a few times, but I cannot find them in any of Jupiter's customization files ('custom.js' or 'notebook.json'). Where are they stored ???

Comment: @JayChakra I'm probably late, but I had the same issue and here are things that must be noticed: 1- your choice of key combinations must be v valid according to the explanations exactly at the bottom of where you assign keys 2- it must not be already used for another command (must not become red when you type it in) 3- you have to hit Enter and see it gets added to the left side of it.

Answer (score 7):

**1. For changing command mode shortcuts:** refer Salvador's answer

**2. For changing edit mode shortcuts:**

Edit the file, *~/.jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json* as explained on https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending/keymaps.html

For example, after replacing the control-enter shortcut to execute code, with command-enter on macOS, the file looks like this:

```
{
  "Notebook": {
    "Toolbar": true,
    "Header": true
  },
  "Cell": {
    "cm_config": {
      "lineNumbers": true
    }
  },
  "keys": {
    "command": {
      "unbind": [
        "ctrl-enter"
      ],
      "bind": {
        "cmdtrl-enter": "jupyter-notebook:run-cell"   
      }
    }, 
    "edit": {
      "unbind": [
        "ctrl-enter"
      ],
      "bind": {
        "cmdtrl-enter": "jupyter-notebook:run-cell"
      }  
    } 
  }   
}
```

Comment: 1. Doesn't this work both command and edit modes? 2. Doesn't Salvador Dali's answer above just edit this file via the GUI?

Comment: Salvador's answer only changed command mode shortcuts, not edit mode

Comment: @ Sachit Nagpal, thanks for the response. Is there documentation to support what you say? I see `"edit": ` in your code snippet above, and I tried with version `6.1.4` and it seems to configure `edit` mode keymap as well.

Comment: My point is that editing `~/.jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json` should work for both command and edit modes.

Comment: You can edit the file accordingly. Do not bind/unbind anything under the edit key then and only add bindings under the command key if you want to only edit the command mode shortcut.

Answer (score 4):

## Adding hotkeys the easy way with nbextensions

1. Install [nbextensions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions).
   `pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions`
2. Then launch jupyter notebook.
3. The the intro page will have a new tab called nbextensions click it and enable Keyboard Shortcut Editor.
4. Now open any notebook click help>keyboard shortcuts
5. Each shortcut will have a pencil icon next to it if you click on it then you can set the shortcut to whatever you want.