# how to bind a command to 'Restart and Run All'?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have recent build of Jupyter than has a menu action allowing you to **Restart & Run All**:

[image]

I would like to add a keyboard shortcut that binds to this action.  I have seen the [documentation](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/3.x/examples/Notebook/Custom%20Keyboard%20Shortcuts.ipynb)  for keyboard customization, but I'm still unsure how to add a keyboard shortcut.

I've built Juypter from source, so based on the help, it would appear that I need to add some code to `notebook/static/custom/custom.js`.

I've tried adding the following:

```
IPython.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts.add_shortcut('meta-r', function (event) {
        IPython.notebook.restart_kernel();
        IPython.notebook.execute_run_all();
        return false;
});
```

However, when I press **[Meta-r]**, the kernel seems to restart but *execute_run_all()* does not get executed.

Comment: **Note** To make it load automatically, you need to wrap it like show [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32159304/776515)

Answer (score 10):

As of Jupyter Notebook 5.0, you can now create and edit keyboard shortcuts directly in menu options. As of now, it's Help -> Edit Keyboard Shortcuts. There's a guide at the bottom of that dialogue box.

The docs on it are here: 
http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Custom%20Keyboard%20Shortcuts.html

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I have in my `custom.js`. For it to work, the shortcut addition has to happen after the app is initialized:

```js
$([Jupyter.events]).on("app_initialized.NotebookApp", function () {
    Jupyter.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts.add_shortcut('0,1', {
    help: 'restart and run all',
    help_index: '0,1',
    handler: function (event) {
      Jupyter.notebook.kernel.restart();
      restartTime = 2000 // decrease this if you have a fast computer
      setTimeout(function(){ Jupyter.notebook.execute_all_cells(); }, restartTime);
      return false;
    }}
  );
});
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me, it restarts but doesn't run the cells. selecting the menu item "restart and run all" does work however ... does the menu item use a different mechanism?

Comment: ah fixed it ... had to increase the timeout to 2000ms, i'm gonna edit the answer for the benifit of people with slow computers!

Comment: Thanks! I'm not using it these days, so I didn't have anything helpful to suggest. :)

Comment: I go through phases of doing EE systems work and writing software. It's software for the time being!

Answer (score 4):

Just in case someone stumbles upon this post looking for the same answer: you need to wait for the kernel to restart with a timeout before executing.
See this [discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/4468#issuecomment-137986736).

In your case, it would give:

```
IPython.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts.add_shortcut('meta-r',
  function (event) {
      IPython.notebook.kernel.restart();
      setTimeout(function(){ IPython.notebook.execute_all_cells(); }, 1000);
      return false;
});
```